# knockd is not started automatically

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, systemd

knock daemon is not starting automatically on my machine. I'm using Kubuntu 18.04.
Here is what I've tried:
I've chaned `START_KNOCKD=1` in `/etc/default/knockd` but it's not working
I've created symlinks in `/etc/rcX.d` pointing to `/etc/inid.d/knockd` (this is a standard script shipped witht the package). X is 1-5
I've added `KNOCKD_OPTS="-i enp0s25"` to my knockd config
I've tried to create NetworkManager script as desribed here [knockd service fails to start when connecting with NetworkManager](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/knockd/+bug/837954) 

I've tried to make it running via systemd by enabling NetWorkManager-wait:
`systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service`

Here is my `/lib/systemd/system/knockd.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Port-Knock Daemon
After=syslog.target network.target
Documentation=man:knockd(1)

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/knockd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/knockd $KNOCKD_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
SuccessExitStatus=0 2 15
ProtectSystem=full
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_RAW CAP_NET_ADMIN

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can start it normally by `/etc/init.d/knockd` from my KDE session and it's working correctly. But I would like it to be started manually and without the need to login to the KDE.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to the end of /lib/systemd/system/knockd.service and seems to work fine:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=knockd.service
```

Regards.

I've opened a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/knockd/+bug/1799697